# Git: Checkout from cloud IDE and local computer

Tags: git

I have the following git environment.

1. A remote git repository
2. A Nitrous cloud IDE(for cloud based development, whenever I am not at home)
3. A local computer(for development, when I am at home)

The remote is added as `live`. I make some changes on my local desktop and push the changes to the repo, then when I try to checkout the changes from Nitrous using `git checkout` it says:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by X commit.
```

Same happens in reverse case. To resolve this issue, I delete the local copy of the project on my dev enviroment and git clone again from the repository to continue with changes I pushed using other development setup.
Where am I going wrong?

Also when I clone the repo on my local dev environment,be it Nitrous or my computer, it loses the information about the remote 'live'. I have to do `git remote add live ...` again in local directory to push new code to the repo. It is so cumbersome.

Comment: Are you pulling from the repo before committing changes? Can you post the commands that you are tried to achieve this.

Comment: It's like, yesterday I did some work on Nitrous, pushed all new changes to the repo. I went home then cloned the repo on my home computer, did some work there,added remote repo again and pushed the changes to repo. I come back on Nitrous today, did the checkout and hence encountered the message.

Comment: you need to pull from the repo before committing any changes, it seems when you came back,to work on nitrous today,you didn't pull the changes that you pushed at home. Check `git log`.on nitrous.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 git add 
 git commit
 git pull origin master(or your working branch)
 git log
```